# How to raise performance of hostapd AP?

Tags: networking, hostapd

So I'm using hostapd on Ubuntu Server 20.04 with Intel 3165 Wi-Fi card installed and decent external antennas connected to it. Everything works just as intended except for performance - test shows about ~30 Mbs if I stay right in front of it.

Here's my `hostapd` config:

```
interface=wlp2s0
driver=nl80211
bridge=lanbr
country_code=RU
ssid=shimos-ap
channel=1
hw_mode=g
preamble=1
macaddr_acl=0
wmm_enabled=1
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[HT20][SHORT-GI-20][TX-STBC][RX-STBC1]
auth_algs=3
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=<password>
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

And `iwconfig` interface output with tx power:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=22 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

So I expected it to hit about 72 Mbs on 20 MHz, but it was even lower than current 30 Mbs until I added ht_capab tags. Speaking frankly, I don't even see which ones I can add staying within 20 MHz. And here's `iw` output part for 2.4 GHz band:

```
        max # scan SSIDs: 20
        max scan IEs length: 425 bytes
        max # sched scan SSIDs: 20
        max # match sets: 11
        max # scan plans: 2
        max scan plan interval: 65535
        max scan plan iterations: 254
        Retry short limit: 7
        Retry long limit: 4
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Device supports RSN-IBSS.
        Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
        Device supports T-DLS.
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
                * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
        Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
                 * P2P-device
        Band 1:
                Capabilities: 0x11ee
                        HT20/HT40
                        SM Power Save disabled
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        TX STBC
                        RX STBC 1-stream
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
                HT Max RX data rate: 150 Mbps
                HT RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
                TX unequal modulation not supported
                HT TX Max spatial streams: 2
                HT TX MCS rate indexes supported may differ
```

Can the problem be with tx power or something else? Btw antennas are up to 1,5 W.

Comment: What's your WiFi `MTU`? Should be 1492, not 1500. Read/Set `MTU` with `ip link ...`. Read `man ip ip-link`.

Comment: @waltinator I changed it with `ip link set wlp2s0 mtu 1492`, but now no speed check is working. Internet is working tho, just cannot say what the speed is now.